# When I paste a java file in eclipse src folder, it doesnt show up

Tags: java, eclipse

I had two java projects, one called MyServer and one MyClient
I wanted to merge two, i.e. just have one project called MyServer.

I copied the .class files and the .java files from MyClient's folder on my harddrive and pasted into my MyServer project folder.

But it doesnt show up in eclipse, I tried refreshing , and then restarting eclipse but none of the java files show up. I can still see MyServer's own source files but not MyClients files that I just pasted.

I am sure I am doing something very simple wrong. Even in Project explorer I cant see the source files

:(

---

Thank you to all for answering.
I used Syam Kumars answer . I deleted the project from eclipse, without deleting contents on disk option , then imported a new project and pointed it to the project folder. Now all the files are visible.

Thx

Comment: are you sure you want the .classes rather than the .java?

Comment: Did you try refershing the project?

Comment: delete the project from eclipse workspace and the open it again.
(PS: Do not delete the contents from disk)

Comment: Why you need .class files just copy java source files from one project to one you want.. and then refresh... projects will automatically create .class files on build.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add it using the eclipse file menu:

**Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Build Path** -> **Libraries** -> **Add External Class Folder**

Comment: This does not answer the question why pasting does not work.